# Accessing array values within class, c++

Tags: c++, class, reference, operator-overloading, this-pointer

I am implementing a set in C++ using an array where elements with values of 0 are not in the set and those with 1 are in the set.  For example, if my set is {1,5} my array would look like: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1].  I am overloading the "/" operator to show the set difference, so if x is in set A and x is not in set B then x is in A/B.  I pass the second Set object to the overloaded function by reference, but I am unable to access it's member variable "arr" which stores the array.

This is the header file:

```
class Set
{
public:
    Set();
    virtual ~Set();
    Set(int);
    int* arr;
    int len;
    Set operator/(const Set&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Set&);
    int* getArray() const;
};
```

And here is the .cpp file:

```
Set::Set(int n) {
    arr = new int[n+1];
    len = n+1;
}

Set Set::operator/(const Set &s){
    int* arr2 = s.getArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < this->len; i++) {
        if (this->arr[i] == 1) {
            if (arr2[i] == 0) {
                this->arr[i] = 1;
            }
            else {
                this->arr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

int* Set::getArray() const { return arr; }
```

If I attempt to print the values of arr2 I get values that appear to be addresses.  How do I access the actual values of arr2?

Edit: I have not learned the "Rule of 3" in any class I've taken so I have no understanding how this could make my code not work.  I've just done some research on it, but I would appreciate a short explanation on how to implement that in this case.  Also, I am not allowed to use containers, so I can't use a vector as suggested in the comments.

Comment: `If I attempt to print the values of arr2` - where is the code that does that?

Comment: You have far more severe problems here, than just overloading an operator. This class apparently fails to comply with the Rule of Three, and, as such, it won't take much more for the entire program to crash and burn, in flaming wreckage due to memory corruption.

Comment: `Set Set::operator/(const Set &s){` -- As stated, this cannot work correctly due to you returning a `Set` by value and `Set` manages a resource (the dynamically allocated memory).  A type being returned by value requires the type to have correct and non-buggy copy semantics.  By not implementing a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator (two parts of the "Rule of 3"), your program cannot be written with any certainty things will work correctly until these are implemented for the `Set` class.  You could bypass all of this if you used `std::vector<int> arr` instead of `int *arr`.